# how to print json array to decoded?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am learning JSON.

**getDatas.php** contents:

```
$query = "SELECT domain FROM access WHERE userid = '".$userid."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$res = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt from clients WHERE domain ='".$row['domain']."'";
    $res2   = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
    $res2   = mysql_fetch_array($res2);

    $res[] = array('domain' => $row['domain'], 'count' => $res2['cnt']);
};
echo json_encode($res);
```

The output is:

```
[{"domain":"www.domain1.com","count":"2"},{"domain":"www.domain2.com","count":"42"},{"domain":"www.domain3.com","count":"61"}]
```

How do I print like this?

How do I get out clean?

```
www.domain1.com - 2
www.domain2.com - 42
www.domain3.com - 61
```

Comment: If you want to output the results in plain text, why are you using `json_encode()` in the first place?

Comment: $res[] = array($row['domain'] => $res2['cnt']); Try this

Comment: @alexeypalamar print: `[{"domain":"www.domain1.com","count":"2"},{"domain":"www.domain2.com","count":"42"},"domain":"www.domain3.com","count":"61"}] ` Unfortunately no change

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT a.domain, COUNT(c.domain) as cnt
FROM `access` as a
LEFT JOIN `clients` as c on c.domain = a.domain
WHERE a.userid = '".$userid."'
GROUP BY c.domain";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$res = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $res[] = array($row['domain'] => $row['cnt']);
};
echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Thank you but output: `[{"www.domain1.com":null},{"www.domain2.com":null},{"www.domain3.com":null}] `

Comment: Writing like this: `[{"www.domain1.com":null},{"www.domain2.com":null},{"www.domain3.com":null}]` Why is not this happening? I don't understand..

Comment: $res[] = array($row['domain'] => $row['cnt']); You need to write $row instead of $res2.

Answer (score -1):

you only need to use

```
echo json_encode($res);
```